# How do I set the Home Time Zone that shows up on the Dual Clock?

Tags: samsung, clock, time-zones

I'm currently traveling with my phone, and my lock screen shows a dual clock with Roaming and Home times. Which is very useful!  Except the Home time is actually from the timezone I originally registered the clock in, NOT the one where I currently live - I've moved timezones since I bought it. Is there any way to set the Home timezone to where I actually live while keeping the dual clock?

I'm on a Samsung Galaxy S7 with Android 6.0.1

Answer (score 14, accepted):

And of course right after I finished writing this question, I figured out the answer. Go to Settings, Lock Screen and Security, Info and App Shortcuts, Dual Clock, and that has a "set home timezone" option. It would've made more sense to put it somewhere in the "Time and Date" Settings section, but oh well.

Comment: Of course. Setting the time is under "lock screen"... face palm

Answer (score 3):

On 7.1.1 settings, lock screen and security, information and face widgets, roaming clock, set your home time zone, along with the roaming clock on.

Comment: If anyone from google reads this, please stop moving stuff, every version the settings are hidden in different places